# Stop fancybox from expanding to whole window

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a control that works well on most sites, but I'm having trouble with an install on one site.

The control uses fancy box to load an iframe with more information about a given element. The problem is that on this one site, the iframe loads in the whole window, and only in IE. I can see it flash in part of the window first, but then it loads for the whole window.

I've checked the control with visual event, and the onclick event is being attached successfully. The fact that the fancybox instance flashes for a second suggests to me that the return value from the click function isn't working correctly.

Does anyone have any advice on how to debug an issue like this?

Comment: And I'm using noConflict() in jQuery, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

check for unwanted trailing commas, for instance:

```
$("#example").fancybox({
'width' : 600,
'height' : 380,
'autoScale' : false,
'type' : 'iframe',
});
```

the last trailing comma after your last API option 'type':'iframe' will break your code in IE.